# Escaping Earth - how could one attempt to find the best solution to this trajectory optimization problem in practice?

Tags: orbit, spacecraft, trajectory, trajectory-design

If there is a satellite in low Earth orbit, with a limited delta-v budget (but high enough to escape Earth) and limited delta-v-rate (thrust), how could one find an acceleration schedule and associated trajectory (that can involve gravity assists using various planets/bodies) that optimizes for the largest spacecraft-Earth distance at a certain time (e.g. 10 years after the starting time)?

Comment: Unfortunately, brute force.

Comment: Wikipedia's [Shooting method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method) "In numerical analysis, the shooting method is a method for solving a boundary value problem by reducing it to an initial value problem. It involves finding solutions to the initial value problem for different initial conditions until one finds the solution that also satisfies the boundary conditions of the boundary value problem. In layman's terms, one "shoots" out trajectories in different directions from one boundary until one finds the trajectory that "hits" the other boundary condition."

Comment: In other words, *What Loren Pechtel said!* But with a modification; you are solving an optimization problem (max/min) rather than a predetermined boundary condition. Without mentioning the available delta-v one can't tell if this is limited primarily to [tag:cis-lunar] space (a mostly four-body problem but with Earth's equatorial bulge) or a bigger n-body problem involving planets. You also haven't mentioned if the spacecraft is to be treated as a point mass (that varies) or if drag and propulsive forces from atmosphere, photon pressure, magnetic fields and solar winds need to be considered.